# How to keep the property names?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I have a class object:

```
public class ChildDetails
{
    [JsonProperty("idConsecutivo")]
    public int SequentialId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("idSemilla")]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("idParentSemilla")]
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("NombreArchivo")]
    public string FileName { get; set; }        
}
```

When execute this line:

```
var childItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ChildDetails>>(resultContent);
```

childItems object property names are: **SequentialId, ParentId, ChildId and FileName**

but when execute this line:

```
var otherChildItems = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(childItems);
```

otherChildItems object property names are: **idConsecutivo, idSemilla, idParentSemilla, NombreArchivo**

How to keep the property names **SequentialId, ParentId, ChildId and FileName** when object is serialized?

Thanks

Comment: If you need to serialize using one set of names and deserialize using a different set of names, then you might want to check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993576/jsonproperty-use-different-name-for-deserialization-but-use-original-name-for

Answer (score 0):

To keep regular property names simply don't add `JsonProperty` attributes that allow you to specify alternative name:

```
public class ChildDetails
{
    public int SequentialId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexei Levenkov