# Change JsonProperty Attribute for same object

Tags: vb.net, json.net, deserialization, httpclient

I need to deserialize an object that has a different name according to Get or Post.

I am working with visual studio (VB) with the class `HttpClient` and Newtonsoft's Json.NET.  When I make the call get the object is presented like this:

- id (int)
- name (str)
- type (int)

When I make the call Post the requested JSON is:

- id (int)
- name (str)
- type_sii (int)

The problem is that my object is declared like this:

```
<JsonProperty ("id")>
 Public Property Id As Integer
<JsonProperty ("name")>
 Public Property Name As String
<JsonProperty ("type")>
 Public Property Type As Integer
```

Then the object its good me when I make the GET call, how can I change the property (Type) when I want to make a post call? (change to "type_sii")

Comment: You could add both properties and decorate with `<JsonProperty("type_sii", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)>`, `<JsonProperty("type", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)>`, setting the unused property to null (`nothing`). Non-reference types can be declared as nullable e.g.,  `Public Property type As Integer?` (Btw, `Type` is bad name).

Comment: Right, what I mean is that a Property decorated with a `JsonProperty` that specifies `NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore`, when set to null is not serialized. Otherwise, implement a custom serializer.

Comment: The simple solution is to create two properties but my question was if I could declare only one.  The "NullValueHandling" i use it in "JsonSerializerSettings" not in properties.

Comment: So basically you want `Type` to have a different name serializing vs deserializing.  If so, are these what you want?  [How to ignore JsonProperty(PropertyName = “someName”) when serializing json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20622492/3744182), [JsonProperty - Use different name for deserialization, but use original name for serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22993576) and/or [json deserialize from legacy property names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33155458/3744182)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JsonProperty - Use different name for deserialization, but use original name for serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993576/jsonproperty-use-different-name-for-deserialization-but-use-original-name-for)

Comment: @dbc No. no type. The difference is in the name.