# Json.NET and field attribute

Tags: c#, json

Let's say I have such a JSON:

```
{
   "A": {
      "variable": "sth"
   }
}
```

I could write the code below for the purpose of serialization and schema generation:

```
public class A
{
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string variable { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public A A { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, there is this *variable* part which is always different. Is it possible to write classes in such a way that would allow me to **serialize and generate schema with ease**? I could just update a certain field before serialization / schema generation and voila! It would use a certain string as the `variable`.

Thanks! :)

Comment: This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882986/overwrite-json-property-name-in-c-sharp