# Dynamic Property Name for JsonProperty in C#

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to create the JSON data using NewtonSoft in c#. I'm using following code-

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "student")]
public List<Student> obj{ get; set; }
```

which will create the list of JSON object for students. I wondered, is there any option to give the PropertyName dynamically, like here I'm using  **PropertyName = "student"**, I want take name dynamically.

For Example I want following JSON Data-

```
{
"id": "123",
 "st1": [
 {
  "Name": "chinna",
  },
 ],
 "st2": [
  {
  "Name": "krishan",
 },
 ]
 }
```

where st1 and st1 are PropertyName which I want to take dynamically.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do. Please post an example of what you want the serialized version to look like so we can better understand the requirement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overwrite Json property name in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882986/overwrite-json-property-name-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Probably, you can serialize `Dictionary<String, Object>` and thus give your properties whatever the names needed.

Comment: Take the name dynamically from where?  Why would you want to change the name of the property at runtime?

Comment: @DaveSwersky, I have update question please check

Comment: You cannot achieve it using a decorator attribute as you have shown in your example, but there may be other ways to do it. Be warned that doing so would make it very difficult to deserialize the data again.

Comment: can u tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Since your root object has fixed properties like `"id"` and variable properties like `"st1"` and `"st2"`, you could consider the solution from [How to deserialize a child object with dynamic (numeric) key names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088941/how-to-deserialize-a-child-object-with-dynamic-numeric-key-names).

Comment: I need to create this type of json String. don't want to deserialize

Comment: @ChinnaRao found any solutions ?