# replacing keys in json with numbers which corresponds to enums

Tags: c#, json, enums

I'm making a json out of a class in c# and for making the json smaller i want to replace the string keys with numbers which correspond to a number of enums.
an example would be a json the looks like this:

```
{
"initdata": 
{
"cell": {
  "apn": "n",
  "userName": "n",
  "password": "n",
  "number": "n"
},
"wifi": {
  "mode": "AP",
  "ssid": "m",
  "password": ","
},
"ports": {
  "p1": "k",
  "p2": "y",
  "p3": "5"
}
}
```

and enums that looks like this :

```
public enum celle { apn, userName, password, number };
public enum wifie { mode, ssid, password };
public enum portse { p1, p2, p3 };
public enum initdatae { cell , wifi , ports};
public enum settingse { initdata, timers }
```

and then I want the json to look like this :

```
{
"0": 
{
"0": {
  "0": "n",
  "1": "n",
  "2": "n",
  "3": "n"
},
"1": {
  "0": "AP",
  "1": "m",
  "2": ","
},
"2": {
  "0": "k",
  "1": "y",
  "2": "5"
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What json serializer do you use?

Comment: If you really need this kind of byte saving, why are you using json? Why not use some custom csv data like this  `0:n,n,n,n|1:AP,m,m|2:k,y,5` (you will save 161-26=135 bytes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Json.Net, for renaming the properties names, take a look here for exemple (there is plenty on Stack Overflow): [Overwrite Json property name in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882986/overwrite-json-property-name-in-c-sharp)

And for the values, I suggest you assign an int to each enum :

```
public enum celle 
{
     apn = 0, 
     userName = 1, 
     password = 2, 
     number = 3 
};
```

And then you cast the enum to an int to get the value before converting it to json:

```
int celleValue = (int)celle.userName;
```

So, in the end your class will look like something like this:

```
public class ClassToConvert()
{
    [JsonIgnore] // this property will not be on the json
    public celle celleValue {get;set;}
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "c1")]
    public int celleShort
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)this.celleValue;
        }
    }
}

public enum celle 
{
     apn = 0, 
     userName = 1, 
     password = 2, 
     number = 3 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have POCO's defined for your input JSON, you may rename your properties as follows:

- deserialize the input JSON into an `ExpandoObject`
- rename the `ExpandoObject`'s properties as desired
- serialize the `ExpandoObject` back to JSON:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var json = @"{
        ""initdata"":  {
            ""cell"": {
                ""apn"": ""n"",
                ""userName"": ""n"",
                ""password"": ""n"",
                ""number"": ""n""
            },
            ""wifi"": {
                ""mode"": ""AP"",
                ""ssid"": ""m"",
                ""password1"": "",""
            },
            ""ports"": {
                ""p1"": ""k"",
                ""p2"": ""y"",
                ""p3"": ""5""
            }
        }
    }";
    dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json, new ExpandoObjectConverter());
    PrepareEnumIds();
    RenameEnumProps(obj as ExpandoObject);
    var shortJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);
    Console.WriteLine(shortJson);
}

public static void RenameEnumProps(ExpandoObject expando)
{
    var expandoDict = expando as IDictionary<string, object>;
    var props = new List<string>(expandoDict.Keys);
    for (var i = props.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var child = expandoDict[props[i]];
        if (child is ExpandoObject)
            RenameEnumProps(child as ExpandoObject);
        if (enumIds.ContainsKey(props[i]))
        {
            expandoDict.Add(enumIds[props[i]], child);
            expandoDict.Remove(props[i]);
        }
    }
}

static Dictionary<string, string> enumIds = new Dictionary<string, string>();

static void PrepareEnumIds()
{
    foreach (var enumType in new[] { typeof(celle), typeof(wifie), typeof(portse), typeof(initdatae), typeof(settingse) })
        foreach (var enumValue in Enum.GetValues(enumType))
            enumIds.Add(enumValue.ToString(), ((int)enumValue).ToString());
}

public enum celle { apn, userName, password, number };
public enum wifie { mode, ssid, password1 };
public enum portse { p1, p2, p3 };
public enum initdatae { cell, wifi, ports };
public enum settingse { initdata, timers }
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IPqxEQ

*Note: I've cheated a little bit by changing one of the `password`s values to make all enum values unique, sorry. This made renaming implementation significantly easier. But this does not affect the main point of implementation. I'll provide a complete implementation when I'll have some more spare time.*