# How to set json field name from property value in run-time .net

Tags: c#, json, .net

How to serialize an object to json through setting json field name from object's property value?

I am using NewtonsoftJson as a json library.

```
public class Data
{
  public string Question {get;set;} = "Test Question?";
  public string Answer {get;set;} = "5";
}
```

expected json output:

```json
{
  "Test Question?": {
    "Answer": "5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Which JSON library are you using? Newtonsoft or System.Text.Json?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Can you change the Model? I would imagine you _could_ get to that result with a dictionary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overwrite Json property name in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882986/overwrite-json-property-name-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary for that:

```
JsonSerializer.Serialize(
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {
            data.Question, new
            {
                data.Answer
            }
        }
    });
```

or if you are using Newtonsoft, you can use the
`JsonConvert.SerializeObject` method for serialization, with the same input.

Comment: Nice, but the OP is using Json.NET, not System.Text.Json

Comment: I have added the Newtonsoft version, although I think the question was mainly about how to construct such an object, not about how to serialize an object generally.

Answer (score 0):

Just for a record

```
var data = new Data();

string json = new JObject { [data.Question] = new JObject { ["Answer"] = data.Answer } }.ToString();
```