# Ignore property from serialization in a collection of a type with Json.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, json.net

Is there an "easy way" to ignore a property from Model serialization on a collection of a type in Asp.Net Core?

**For example**

```
public sealed class MainViewModel
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  [JsonIgnore("PropertyInSubViewModel")]
  public ICollection<SubViewModel> Products { get; set; }
}
```

The idea was to remove some property in `SubViewModel` from model serialization, so when I get it in my action, it would have its default value set, not the one set through the request.

Comment: Why would you use a model that has properties you don't want anyway?

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to ignore some property of `SubViewModel` when nested inside `MainViewModel`, but not when serialized independently?  Or do you really want to ignore some property of `SubViewModel` when inside a specific method call?  The former is quite tricky, see [Json.NET serialize by depth and attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36159424).  The latter might be easier, see [ASP.NET Core API JSON serializersettings per request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44828302) plus [Exclude property from serialization via custom attribute (json.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13588022).

Comment: I want to ignore a property of `SubViewModel` when nested inside `MainViewModel`, when used independently, it would expose all the properties.

Answer (score 2):

Not with `JsonIgnore`. That can only be applied on the actual property that you want to ignore, and is constant at that point. However, JSON.NET does have support for [conditional serialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm). The easiest and most straight-forward is adding a `ShouldSerialize*` method to your class. You'd obviously need to determine some condition you could lean on for the determination, but that could be a straight-forward as literally setting some boolean on your sub view model instances. Basically, you just add something like:

```
public class SubViewModel
{
    ...

    public bool ShouldSerializePropertyInSubViewModel()
    {
         // return true or false to either allow or disallow serializing the property on this instance
    }
}
```